# How to do bulk update in rails on habtm association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

```
#user.rb

has_and_belongs_to_many :groups

#group.rb

has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

I want to associate groups to users such that `many users can be associated to many groups`.

Front end side of the application is sending the `user_ids` and `group_ids` to the update method.

So in the `UsersController`, i've found out each user and associated that user with the groups.

```
def update
  users = User.where(id: [325, 326])
  users.each { |user| user.update(group_ids: [1, 2])}
end
```

I need to know the standard way of updating the associated records and what is the most efficient way of updating associated records?

Answer (score 1):

There is a method [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all)

```
def update
  users = User.where(id: [325, 326])
  users.update_all group_ids: [1, 2]
end
```

Comment: update_all doesn't work as group_ids is associated column. Although i tried your solution but i'm getting this error.

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2"
LINE 1: UPDATE "users" SET "group_ids" = 1,2 WHERE "an...
                                                         ^
: UPDATE "users" SET "group_ids" = 1,2 WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" IN (325, 326)`

Comment: Which columns do your models have?

Comment: It needs to be updated in the join table: `groups_users` . The column in `User` table are `name`,  `description` and the `Group` table has `name` , `description`.

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to update? Is it creating new associations between users and groups?

Comment: Yes she is associating users to groups.

Comment: The above syntax is not correct and gets the error`TypeError: can't quote Array`. See more examples in [Rails update_all](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) method.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest ActiveRecord-native approach is to create a model class for your join table and use that, e.g.:

```rb
class GroupsUser < ActiveRecord::Base; end
```

(Note that the model class is `GroupsUser` so that by convention ActiveRecord will know it's for the `groups_users` table. It's a little goofy but it works.)

Then you can use `insert_all` on the join table:

```rb
user_ids = [325, 326]
group_ids = [1, 2]

values = user_ids.map do |uid| 
           group_ids.map do |gid|
             { user_id: uid, group_id: gid }
           end
         end.flatten
# => [{user_id: 325, group_id: 1}, {user_id: 325, group_id: 2}, {user_id=>326, group_id: 1}, {user_id: 326, group_id: 2}]

GroupsUser.insert_all(values)
```

Note though that this is is `insert_all`, not `update_all` -- `update_all` doesn't really make sense for a join table. We're adding values, not replacing them. (At least on PostgreSQL and SQLite, if there's a unique index on the join table, duplicates will be ignored -- on MySQL you might need to jump through some more hoops to exclude existing relationships, unless you're deleting those anyway as below.)

If you want to replace any existing associations, you'll need to delete those explicitly:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  GroupsUser.delete_all(user_id: user_ids)
  # and/or GroupsUser.delete_all(group_id: group_ids), depending
  GroupsUser.insert_all(values)
end
```

Also worth noting: there's no need to put `GroupsUser` in `app/models/groups_user.rb`; if this is the only code that uses it, you can put it right in the file where it's used. This is especially useful in migrations.